# How to get the "my document" directory path of current account?

Tags: windows, mfc, visual-c++

Usually,we could get the my document's path by read the reg's value by the path:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Personal.

But if I login in a normal account, and I right click the program file 
and choose run as admin . Then the program read the reg's path above didn't get the
current account's my document path,but the admin's path.

Have some correct way which can make sure to get the current account's my document path?

Comment: I try the code , but that way is still can't make sure open the current account's path when I login in a normal account and run as admin.

Comment: I think that I put some data to the user's my document,then I want to get the data from different account. That is not the correct way. I should put the data in the common my document.So I can get the data from all account.By the way,thanks for your answer.